# How to get the sharing icons to display in mosaico?

Tags: mosaico

I've got the problem described in https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/mosaico-extension-v20-beta3-etal

The image location is

`/files/civicrm/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/img/social_def/facebook_ok.png`

The HTML has it relative to templates

```
<img src="https://dmo.ecolsoc.org.au/templates/versafix-1/img/social_def/google+_ok.png" alt="Google+" border="0" class="socialIcon" style="border: 0px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0px; border-radius: 100%;">
```

am I missing a .htaccess or extension variable?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the same issue as here perhaps: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/160

If you read the detail, the problem has been fixed for new templates, but old templates created before the fix will still fail most likely

Comment: There is a beta-3 at https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/tags. I could also manually add the sharing icons.